# How to put figures above the text

Tags: floats, positioning

I am writing my first paper in latex and have problem when I am about to finish the paper i.e. at the end of the paper.

I used the following code and want to display the figures first before the text.

```
\begin{figure*}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[]{fig5.png}
       \label{fig:my_label}
  \end{figure*}
  
  \begin{figure*}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[]{fig6.png}
    Figure 6: title of figure
       \label{fig:my_label}
  \end{figure*}

\section{5.Discussion}

In this work, we provided ....... two paragraph I added

then 

\section{Conclusion and future work}

In this work, we describe .... two paragraphs
```

But the problem is that both the figures comes below these texts. I need to put the figures first and then Discussion and conclusion parts to conclude my paper. How can I do that?

Comment: Does [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/8633/2417) answer your question?

Comment: @IanThompson, I used "h" option already and now after your comment, also added \usepackage{float} but the problem persist

Comment: `H` not `h`, but it's worth taking the time to read the reasons for _not_ doing this.

Comment: @IanThompson, with H the figures disappear.  With "h" figures are showed but at the end of document i.e. before text

Comment: That's strange. To fix it we'll probably need an example code that reproduces the problem. You can use `\rule{4cm}{4cm}` in place of the `\includegraphics` commands, and change the sizes as necessary.

Comment: @IanThompson, yes it seems strange because in the rest of document earlier, I used the same code for figures (and tables) and it work fine but these two figures produce problems at the end of the document/paper.

Comment: Uh, figure* only supports [tp].  You need dblfloatfix to support [b].  figure* never supports [h] or [H].  You **can** use multicols or flowfram to modify the columns.

Comment: I forgot to mention but I am using two column page (IEEE format)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}%manage images
\usepackage{multicol}%set multicolumn features in page 
\usepackage{float}%Places the float at precisely the location in the LaTeX code


\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=3cm, height=2cm]{fig5.png}
  \caption{fig: title of figure}

\end{figure} 
\columnbreak
  
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering  
\includegraphics[width=3cm, height=2cm]{fig6.png}
  \caption{Figure: title of figure}

\end{figure}
\end{multicols}

\section{5.Discussion}

In this work, we provided ....... two paragraph I added

then 

\section{Conclusion and future work}

In this work, we describe .... two paragraphs

\end{document}
```

You can control image width and height using width and height values.

Comment: Welcome to TeX:SE! OP ask for positioning of `figure*`. For it placement see @ John Kormylo comment.

Comment: Hi @Zarko OP wants a figure first, before the text. I think in this way it can be done.

Comment: Who knows what OP is after. I doubt  that her/his article start with figure (I newer see such article) so before it is some text and image (over two column?) should be before some some section title. Apparently OP nor you are not aware of potential problems with your solution.  You should look https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat/39020#39020 ...

Comment: Thanks, I'll read.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your question is duplicate to [how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat/39020#39020). Anyway, due to specific of your question (which is not very clear), some possibilities are summarized below.

In the first, advantage of `float` environments are that they can float! It is not a sin, if for better looking of document, image is moved after some section title :-).

From use of the `figure*` environment can be concluded that you use two column article and that you like to span figures over both columns. In this case `figure*` only supports `[tp]` (see @John Kormylo comment) and will always appear on the top of the next page (consequently you can float's omit placeholder):

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-3]
\begin{figure*}
\centering
\includegraphics[height=33mm,width=\linewidth]{example-image-A}
  \caption{fig: title of figure}
\end{figure*}

\begin{figure*}
\centering
\includegraphics[height=33mm,width=\linewidth]{example-image-B}
  \caption{Figure: title of figure}
\end{figure*}

\section{Discussion}
\lipsum[4-5]

\section{Conclusion and future work}
\lipsum[6-7]

\end{document}
```

[image]

In the case that you estimate, that at bottom of page is sufficient space, it will be placed here by help of package `stfloats`:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{multicol} 
\usepackage{stfloats}   % <---

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{figure*}[b]
\centering
\includegraphics[height=33mm,width=\linewidth]{example-image-A}
  \caption{fig: title of figure}
\end{figure*}
\begin{figure*}[b]
\centering
\includegraphics[height=33mm,width=\linewidth]{example-image-B}
  \caption{Figure: title of figure}
\end{figure*}
\lipsum[1-3]

\section{Discussion}
\lipsum[4-5]

\section{Conclusion and future work}
\lipsum[6-7]

\end{document}
```

As you see, here images are inserted earlier in text that in page is sufficient space for them. This "trick" is handy in the many cases.

[image]

However, in the case of use `figure`, i.e. that images widths are equal to column width, than you can use figure placement specifier for example `htb` and newer just `[h]`. In later case can happen that TeX will push figure on the end of document if in text is not enough space at point of insertion.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{multicol} 

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-6]
\begin{figure}[ht] % <---
\centering
\includegraphics[height=33mm,width=\linewidth]{example-image-A}
  \caption{fig: title of figure}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\includegraphics[height=33mm,width=\linewidth]{example-image-B}
  \caption{Figure: title of figure}
\end{figure}

\section{Discussion}
\lipsum[4-5]

\section{Conclusion and future work}
\lipsum[6-7]

\end{document}
```

[image]